# ERROR: expected unqualified-id before '[' and ERROR: 'users' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I trying to make a program, in which you write login and password, and, if user exists in class, it shows permissions (ex. Carl can read and execute files). Right now I have two bugs:

```
22:9: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
36:23: error: 'users' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm new to c++, so I'm not sure what should I do. Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    class User {
    public:
        string login;   
        string password;
        bool R;
        bool W;
        bool X;
        User() = default;

        User(string login, string password, bool r, bool w, bool x);
    };

    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string login, password;

    string User[] users = new User[]
    {
        new User("Alice", "Cooper", false, true, true),
        new User("Bob", "Dylan", false, true, false),
        new User("Carl", "Perkins", true, false, true)
    };

    cout << "\nEnter login: " << endl;
    cin >> login;

    cout << "\nEnter password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;

    bool userFound = false;
    User user = users[i];
    for (int i=0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {

        if (user.login == login && user.password == password)
        {
            userFound = true;
            cout << "\nCan read: " << user.R;
            cout << "\nCan write: " << user.W;
            cout << "\nCan execute: " << user.X;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!userFound)
    {
        cout << "\nUser not found" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to take out `string` from `string User[] users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string User[] users = new User[]
{
    new User("Alice", "Cooper", false, true, true),
    new User("Bob", "Dylan", false, true, false),
    new User("Carl", "Perkins", true, false, true)
};
```

That’s not valid C++ (it looks like you’re somehow mixing C++ and Java syntax). First off, you slipped an accidental `string` into the declaration (and you did not declare `string` — you need to `#include <string>`!). Secondly, C arrays are declared as follows:

```
Type var[N];
```

Thirdly, you can’t initialise a C array with a pointer (returned from `new`).

Fourthly, `new Type[]` requires an *array size*.

Fifthly, you cannot initialise an array of `User`s with *pointers* (`new User` creates a `User*`).

All these problems are solved by using a `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<User> users{
    User("Alice", "Cooper", false, true, true),
    User("Bob", "Dylan", false, true, false),
    User("Carl", "Perkins", true, false, true)
};
```

Comment: In addition, he will also have a issue initializing the "user" variable outside the for loop.
The variable "i" is not declared out of the for loop, and even so, it will not be incremented and he we loop on the same element.